# after grouping in R how to get top cateogircal variables and their numeric values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, group

I have different seasons for NBA players and I use by to get the sum of points every season.

```
 by( NBA$pts , NBA$season , sum )


NBA$season: 1996-97
 [1] 3539.5
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
NBA$season: 1997-98
[1] 3489`
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
NBA$season: 1999-00
[1] 3497.8
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
NBA$season: 2000-01
[1] 3444.8
```

I want to get the top 10 scoring players (NBA$player_name) and their points (pts) in every season and plot them with barplot

Answer (score 1):

We could use `tidyverse` to return the top 10 `sum` of 'pts by 'season' (`slice_max`) and then get the barplot with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
out <- NBA %>%
    group_by(player_name, season) %>%
    summarise(pts = sum(pts, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    group_by(season) %>%
    slice_max(n = 10, order_by = pts) %>%
    ungroup

ggplot(out, aes(x = season, y = pts, fill = player_name)) + 
    geom_col()
```

Comment: I think I haven't explained my question well! I mean how can I get player_names and their corresponding pts in each season?

Comment: @Y.esk your code used only `season` and `pts`

Comment: yes! I need to add some lines using `NBA$player_name` but I'm not sure if I am in the right direction

Comment: @Y.esk do you need the sum by season or sum by season and player_name?

Comment: I need to group by season and get the top 10 players and their scores

Comment: @Y.esk when you say scores, is it the `sum` scores or the individual scores before the sum?

Comment: In each season, I need to get the sum of scores of each player

Comment: @Y.esk then you just need `group_by(season, player_name)`

Comment: @Y.esk try the updated solution

Comment: thanks, I tried the solution and I got top player  in each season, however my aim was to get the top 10 players in each season and to plot their frequencies. To know the frequencies of players ranked in the top 10 in all seasons and not a must to be ranked number one

Comment: @Y.esk for that you need to add `group_by(season)` as in the update

Comment: Thanks! I got top 10 in each season. Is there a way to get top 10 over all seasons?

Comment: @Y.esk that was the previous code

Comment: The previous was for getting the top player in each season, the updated get the top 10 players in each season and this is closer to the solution. Now I want to get the top 10 over all seasons, so maybe by aggregating?